# Get the real php page name after redirection

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I wished to know how to retrieve the real page name from JavaScript, i.e. not the one showed in the browser address bar.

For example my .htaccess has a directive: `DirectoryIndex bibi.php`, so when I'll reach `.../` it will show `.../bibi.php`. 
However, `location.href` and `document.URL` from JavaScript will still show `.../`.

How to get `.../bibi.php` from JavaScript even after a redirection?

Comment: JavaScript running in the web-browser cannot know which file was processed on the server. You'll have to write this information down, e.g. into the HTML source code: `<body data-file-name="<?php ... ?>">`.

Comment: I do not celebrate Western Christmas. The client has no knowledge of what is going on on the server. This is impossible.

Comment: Thank you, this is a valid answer, please post it as so @ŠimeVidas

Comment: And I always mention happy Eid al-Fitr to my Lebanese friends even though I'm not celebrating it myself. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript running in the web-browser cannot know which file was processed on the server. You'll have to pass this information to the web-browser, e.g. by writing it into the HTML source code:

```
<body data-file-name="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">
```

I took the PHP code from here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/get-current-file-name/

Comment: Thank you. I used a meta-tag instead but this is the idea, your help was welcome.